# How to redirect to the dashboard from a URL?

Tags: traefik

I currently access the V2 dashboard through `http://traefik.my.server:8080/dashboard/` (Traefik runs in a docker container and 8080 is exposed to the host).
I would like to change that so that the dashboard is available at  `http://traefik.my.server/dashboard`

I tried to add the following labels to configure this behavior but I get a `404` when accessing `http://traefik.my.server/dashboard`

```
- traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.my.server:`) && Path(`/dashboard`)
- traefik.http.services.dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
- traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entryPoints=http
```

(the `http` entrypoint is port `80`)

What is the correct way to set up such redirectio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommend read:

- https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/operations/dashboard/#secure-mode
- https://blog.containo.us/traefik-2-0-docker-101-fc2893944b9d
- https://github.com/containous/blog-posts/tree/master/2019_09_10-101_docker

FYI it's not redirection but a routing.

https://community.containo.us/t/how-to-redirect-to-the-dashboard-from-a-url/4082/2

Comment: Thank you for your help on the Traefik forum (https://community.containo.us/t/how-to-redirect-to-the-dashboard-from-a-url/4082). I posted the working configuration as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Idez help at https://community.containo.us/t/how-to-redirect-to-the-dashboard-from-a-url/4082, a working configuration is

The `docker-compose` file:

```
services:
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /etc/docker/container-data/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain.org`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=lan
      - traefik.http.middlewares.lan.ipwhitelist.sourcerange=192.168.10.0/24, 192.168.20.0/24
      - traefik.enable=true
version: "3"
```

Configuration file

```
global:
  sendAnonymousUsage: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"
api:
  dashboard: true
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
    defaultRule: "Host(`{{ index .Labels \"com.docker.compose.service\" }}.mydomain.org`)"
log:
  level: INFO
  #level: DEBUG
certificatesResolvers:
  le:
      acme:
          email: le@mydomain.org
          storage: /etc/traefik/acme.json
          tlsChallenge: {}
          #caServer: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
```